# Android device isn't showing up in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I want to debug on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 but the device isn't showing up in Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac. In addition, the tablet isn't showing up in Finder even though it's plugged in with a USB cabel. I use macOS High Sierra on my iMac.

Why is the Android tablet not showing up in Visual Studio?

[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1zZo.png)

Comment: Did you try on another computer ? Also, is your tablet showing a popup asking for authorization or something like that ? Please add details and what you've ever try.

Comment: I have just tried on this computer. I have no other computers. The tablet isn't asking for authorization.

Answer (score 2):

It works now. It was necessary to enable the developer options and usb debugging.
[developer options and usb debugging](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/enabling_usb_debugging_on_an_android_device.html)

Comment: Had to restart my Android device in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Late-joining the show to add the following in 2024:

It seems there's some sort of a weird bug plaguing the latest MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1 in terms of Android detection even if developer-options + USB-debugging is enabled on the phone's side.

Setups that used to work just fine suddenly work only sporadically because the phone disappears from the phone-list in Rider/VisualStudio.

If you run into this issue then do this:

- Unplug your phone
- Go to developer settings and revoke all usb authorizations
- Replug the phone and accept the connection both on the mac-ui and on the phone-ui (yes we now get prompts on both sides - previously only the phone would prompt)
- If this doesn't work reboot the phone and/or your mac and go through these steps again